# What does {0:{w}d} mean in python's format() method?

Tags: python

```py
def print_formatted(number):

    width = len("{0:b}".format(number))

    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        print("{0:{w}d} {0:{w}o} {0:{w}X} {0:{w}b}".format(i, w = width))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```

This is the code for converting a given number to different bases, i.e., binary, decimal, octal, hexadecimal. We were also supposed to give space padding of the length of the binary number and separate each with length 1. I am unable to understand what {0:{w}d} means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation:

```
#Decimal representation
"{0:d}".format(value)

#Octal representation
"{0:o}".format(value)

#Hexadecimal representation
"{0:x}".format(value)

#Binary representation
"{0:b}".format(value)
```

and in your code:

```
number = 6  # for example
width = len("{0:b}".format(number))

for i in range(1, number + 1):
    print("{0:{w}d} {0:{w}o} {0:{w}X} {0:{w}b}".format(i, w=width))
```

output:

```
  1   1   1   1
  2   2   2  10
  3   3   3  11
  4   4   4 100
  5   5   5 101
  6   6   6 110
```

Where `w` is the passed argument to the `format` function that is assigned to the variable `width` and, if we check the value of it

```
width = len("{0:b}".format(number))
print(width)
3
```

It's the length (3) of the binary representation (110) of this given `number` (6 here).

So, it provides the spacing.

I hope it makes you understand the meaning of `{0:{w}d}`.

Comment: it just simply takes the value of `w` which is `width`. so it provides the given spacing as you can see in the output above.

Comment: I think the answer would benefit from explicitly stating that the {w} determines the width of the string resulting from the number formatting.